# Parse data from website using re module

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping

I am trying to parse some data from a website using re module. The problem is that I am new to the module and not sure how exactly to parse the data.

[image]

What I am trying to parse is the link in "href=" . What do I need to enter in the parenthesis in my code?

```
body_links = re.findall(r'<a>()</a>', str(resp1Data))
```

Comment: Read the documentation then, make an attempt. It's going to be something like 'href=\"{1}\"'

Comment: Please paste literal text, not images of text.

Answer (score 1):

Instead use beautifulsoup package of python. Very useful for parsing web-content.

Example :

`from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
html = '''<a href="some_url">next</a><span class="class"><a href="another_url">later</a></span>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print a['href']`

This will give you all hyperlinks from the given html.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The code you're looking for is:

```
re.findall(r'href="(.+?)"', str(resp1Data))
```

This matches everything directly after `href=` and in between `""`. The `.` stands for "any character", `+` for "one or more occurrences", and `?` for "non-greedy", meaning the shortest possible match will be used.

Please read up on regular expressions, this is pretty basic and important stuff.